# Unable to Convert Scanner to File, Scanner at end of file, fileNotFoundException

Tags: java, file, io, java.util.scanner, eof

I'm required to take a file name as input for a scanner in one method and use that scanner as reference to the file path for the rest of my code in all other methods.

I'm learning file i/o, and for this project I'm supposed to take a file name as input, count the number of lines in the file and put each line into an array.

My issue comes in during the `FileUtils.countRecords` method. After returning a file type in `FileUtils.openInputFile` and then taking that data and putting it into a scanner (variables inf and fin in the code) I'm supposed to take that scanner and use it to point to a file again. `(File input=new File(scanner))`
*My instructor gave us a hint that "The Scanner is at the EOF and will need to be reset" though I haven't been able to find any 'end of file' documentation that would help me here.

From main method (!this can not be changed!)

```
File inf = null;
int total, choice;
String [] words = null;
Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in), fin = null;
inf = FileUtils.openInputFile(kb);
fin = new Scanner(inf);
total = FileUtils.countRecords(fin, 1);
fin.close();
```

FileUtils.openInputFile(kb) returns the type File after being given the file's path.

```
public static int countRecords(java.util.Scanner fin,int linesPer)
{   
    File input = new File(fin.toString()); //fileNotFoundException here
    File input = new File(fin); //also throws filenotfoundexception
```

When I try `System.out.print(fin)` or `System.out.print(fin.toString())` I get this:

```
java.util.Scanner[delimiters=\p{javaWhitespace}+][position=0][match valid=false][need input=false][source closed=false][skipped=false][group separator=\,][decimal separator=\.][positive prefix=][negative prefix=\Q-\E][positive suffix=][negative suffix=][NaN string=\Q?\E][infinity string=\Q?\E]
```

Which is obviously not a file name or path. I'm wondering if I need to convert my scanner into something else before assigning my file variable to it. Or if there is something like .toString() that would turn the above scanner properties into readable text. Or how to "reset the scanner at the eof."

Answer (score 0):

So I guess the `scanner fin` doesn't hold the path/file name. It is a reference to the open file itself, therefore all I needed to do was count each line from the file like so:

```
while(fin.hasNext())
        {
            fin.nextLine();
            count ++;
        }
```